Laravel + Nginx in Kubernetes. Asset routes return error 404
I am using a Laravel app I found on GitHub for a proyect where I try to containeraize apps for kubernetes. Nginx successfully connects with my app but It shows a blank page.
Uppon closer inspection I find that when accessing the webserver through Nginx messes with the asset routes somehow, causing it to look for the assets inside the webserver (http://laravel-nginx/build/assets/[asset name]) pod instead of the laravel pod, resulting in a 404 error and a blank screen.
I tried using php artisan serve to setup a webserver inside the laravel pod at port 8000 and resulted in the apllication working just fine. The routes work as expected (http://localhost:8000/build/assets/[asset name]) and I can even access from outside the cluster with proper port forwarding.
Why is remote webserver causing this error? Is it an env variable or something like that?
Im guessing that maybe it has something to do do with Vite path config
This is my Nginx conf:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-config
data:
  config : |
    server {
      listen 80 default_server;
      listen [::]:80 default_server;
      root /app/public;

      index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

      server_name _;

      location / {
          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
      }

      location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
      location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

      error_page 404 /index.php;

      location ~ \.php$ {
          include fastcgi_params;
          fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
          fastcgi_pass laravel:9000;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
      }

      location ~ /\.ht {
          deny all;
      }

      location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
      }
    }

And my laravel config:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: laravel
data:
  APP_NAME: "Laravel"
  APP_ENV: "production"
  APP_DEBUG: "false"
  # Complete with an external URL if you have one. 
  APP_URL: "http://localhost"
  
  # Modified the LOG_CHANNEL to stdout for Kubernetes
  LOG_CHANNEL: "stdout"
  LOG_LEVEL: "debug"
  DB_CONNECTION: "mysql"
  DB_HOST: "mysql"
  DB_PORT: "3306"
  DB_DATABASE: "forge"
  
  BROADCAST_DRIVER: "log"
  CACHE_DRIVER: "file"
  FILESYSTEM_DRIVER: "local"
  QUEUE_CONNECTION: "sync"
  # Using redis as a session driver
  SESSION_DRIVER: "file"
  SESSION_LIFETIME: "120"
  
  MEMCACHED_HOST: "memcached"
  
  REDIS_HOST: "redis"
  REDIS_PORT: "6379"
  
  MAIL_MAILER: "smtp"
  MAIL_HOST: "mailhog"
  MAIL_PORT: "1025"
  MAIL_ENCRYPTION: "null"
  MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS: "null"
  MAIL_FROM_NAME: "${APP_NAME}"
  
  AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "us-east-1"
  AWS_BUCKET: ""
  AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT: "false"
  
  PUSHER_APP_ID: ""
  PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER: "mt1"
  
  VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY: "${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"


apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: laravel
type: Opaque
stringData:
  APP_KEY: "ABCDEF123ERD456EABCDEF123ERD456E"
  DB_USERNAME: "forge"
  DB_PASSWORD: "forge"
  REDIS_PASSWORD: "null"
  MAIL_USERNAME: "null"
  MAIL_PASSWORD: "null"
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ""
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ""
  PUSHER_APP_KEY: ""
  PUSHER_APP_SECRET: ""
  MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY: "${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"

My vite.conf.js:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        host: 'localhost'
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel(['resources/ts/main.tsx']),
        react(),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': '/resources/ts',
        },
    },
});


The issue was actually caused by a hardcoded fetch that was pointing to an unexisting server, just fixed the path and everything works fine.
